how to use custom query in springboot (elasticsearch) [search method not found error]
there I am Aditya. Currently making backend for ecommerce website as personal project. While making it I came to know about elasticsearch which seems to use some AI logic and helps to do fuzzy search. So i decided to use it for my products table. but the issue in its 8.+ version they have implemented https for security of elasticsearch api and the tutorials are out of date. But after some research I found how to connect springboot to elasticsearch using ssl contexts and Now all the basic functions are working for ElasticsearchRepository but the issue arise when I try to use custom queries.
here's my product table:
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Document(indexName = "products")
public class Product {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private int userId;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private double price;
    private int stock;
    private int categoryId;
    private String image1;
    private String image2;
    private String image3;
    private String image4;
    private String image5;
    private String image6;
    private String image7;
    private String image8;
    private String image9;
}

My ElasticsearchRepository:
@Repository
public interface ProductESRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Product, String> {

    List<Product> findByName(String name);

    Product findByUserIdAndName(int userId, String name);

    List<Product> findByUserId(int userId);

    List<Product> search(Query query, Class<Product> class1);
}

My ElasticSearchClient:
@Configuration
public class ESClient {

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchClient getElasticsearchClient() {
        // Create a RestClientBuilder with your Elasticsearch host and port.
        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "https"));

        // Set up custom HttpClientConfigCallback to load SSL certificate and
        // truststore.
        RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback httpClientConfigCallback = new HttpClientConfigImpl();
        builder.setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientConfigCallback);

        // Create a ElasticsearchClient with the RestClient.
        RestClient restClient = builder.build();

        // Create a ElasticsearchClientTransport with the RestClient and
        // JacksonJsonpMapper.
        RestClientTransport restClientTransport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

        // Create and return the ElasticsearchClient.
        return new ElasticsearchClient(restClientTransport);
    }
}

and finaly my custom HttpAsyncClientBuilder:
type here@Configuration
public class HttpClientConfigImpl implements HttpClientConfigCallback {

    // to establish connection between elasticsearch instance
    @Override
    public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpAsyncClientBuilder) {
        try {
            // create credentials
            final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            UsernamePasswordCredentials usernamePasswordCredentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("elastic",
                    "nothing");
            credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, usernamePasswordCredentials);
            httpAsyncClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);

            // import truststore file
            String trustLocationStore = "/home/all_father/elasticsearch-8.14.1/config/certs/truststore.p12";
            File trustLocationFile = new File(trustLocationStore);

            // load the truststore
            SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(trustLocationFile,
                    "nothing".toCharArray());

            // provide the ssl context to the client builder
            SSLContext sslContext = sslContextBuilder.build();
            httpAsyncClientBuilder.setSSLContext(sslContext);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return httpAsyncClientBuilder;
    }
}

This is proper working code But the error**[search method not found for products]** arises when i try to do custom query. I have tried every single way(StringQuery, @Query, Query DSL, etc) of implementing custom query but none of the way is working.
